# How do I insert an image in php

Tags: php

This is the code that I have but when I try to run it, I get an error saying, 
`"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'src' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in H:\xampp\htdocs\teacher\page1.php on line 33"`

The code shows as below:

```
echo "<div id = 'Image1'>"
<img src='path/to/Desert.jpg' alt='photo of me' />"</div>";
echo "<div id = 'Title'>". $output['Title'] . "</div>";
echo "<div  id = 'Initials'>" . $output['Cipher']."</div>";
echo "<div id = 'LastName'>" .$output['LastName'] . "</div>";
echo "<div id = 'Level'>".$output['SaleryLevel'] . "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

dude you forgot a semicolon ; on line 33.. cant you even read the error?

Comment: can he even read english? doesn't seem like it